# Write a class with some properties and indexed

Tags: c#, beginner, collections, constructor

Is there a better way to write it? I need the best way to write it. It is this principle? Please show me a better way

it breaks SRP?

```
 public class PlacementLocation
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
}

public class PlacementLocations : PlacementLocation
{
    private void SetLocationInList()
    {
        _placementLocations = new List<PlacementLocation>
            {
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 1, Row = 9, Location = 1},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 2, Row = 9, Location = 2},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 3, Row = 9, Location = 3},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 4, Row = 9, Location = 4},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 5, Row = 9, Location = 5},
            };
    }

    private List<PlacementLocation> _placementLocations;

    public PlacementLocations()
    {
        _placementLocations = new List<PlacementLocation>();
        SetLocationInList();
    }

    public Tuple<int, int> this[int location]
    {
        get { return new Tuple<int, int>(_placementLocations[location].Row, _placementLocations[location].Column); }
    }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            PlacementLocation singleOrDefault =
                _placementLocations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Column == column && d.Row == row);
            return singleOrDefault != null ? singleOrDefault.Location : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update :**

```
  public class PlacementLocations
{

    #region Variables

    private readonly List<PlacementLocation> _placementLocations;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public PlacementLocations(List<PlacementLocation> placementLocations)
    {
        _placementLocations = placementLocations;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public Tuple<int, int> FindRowColumn(int location)
    {
        return GetRowColumn(location);
    }

    public int FindLocation(int row, int column)
    {
        return GetLocation(row, column);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Indexes

    public Tuple<int, int> this[int location]
    {
        get { return GetRowColumn(location); }
    }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return GetLocation(row, column); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private Tuple<int, int> GetRowColumn(int location)
    {
        return new Tuple<int, int>(_placementLocations[location].Row, _placementLocations[location].Column);
    }

    private int GetLocation(int row, int column)
    {
        PlacementLocation singleOrDefault =
            _placementLocations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Column == column && d.Row == row);
        return singleOrDefault != null ? singleOrDefault.Location : 0;
    }

    #endregion

}

public class LocationsFactory
{
    public static PlacementLocations GetPredefinedLocations()
    {
        var placementLocationList = new List<PlacementLocation>
            {
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 1, Row = 9, Location = 1},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 2, Row = 9, Location = 2},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 3, Row = 9, Location = 3},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 4, Row = 9, Location = 4},
                new PlacementLocation {Column = 5, Row = 9, Location = 5},
            };

        return new PlacementLocations(placementLocationList);
    }
}
```

Comment: why have you edited the initial question code? Now it is not clear what question is about and answers below don't make any sense...

Comment: update question .

Comment: you still haven't extracted the values from the class (what is told in answers below). What will you do if you need _another_ location values - write one more class? :)

Comment: and you don't need a specific method which does just '_placementLocations = placementLocations;' - that is usually placed directly in constructor...

Comment: The question was edited. Is it correct?

Comment: At least the initial critical problems are solved.

Comment: However you added regions everywhere. IMO the best would be to put the class in a logical order where you can read it top to bottom like a short newspaper article. Regions clutter the code and impede readability.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault  :Please give me more information about IMO

Comment: @SunRise it means 'In My Opinion'

Comment: @IharS: Do you think there is another problem?There is another critical problem?

Answer (score 2):

The inheritance doesn't make sense. 'PlacementLocations' is the object representing a collection of 'PlacementLocation' objects.

```
public class PlacementLocations
{
    private List<PlacementLocation> _placementLocations;

    public PlacementLocations(List<PlacementLocation> locations)
    {
        _placementLocations = locations;
    }

    public Tuple<int, int> this[int location]
    {
        get { return new Tuple<int, int>(_placementLocations[location].Row, _placementLocations[location].Column); }
    }

    public int this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            PlacementLocation singleOrDefault =
                _placementLocations.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Column == column && d.Row == row);
            return singleOrDefault != null ? singleOrDefault.Location : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Class should not contain particular initialization values: use constructor parameters instead and initialize externally:

```
...

var placementLocationList = new List<PlacementLocation>
{
    new PlacementLocation { Column = 1, Row = 9, Location = 1 },
    new PlacementLocation { Column = 2, Row = 9, Location = 2 },
    new PlacementLocation { Column = 3, Row = 9, Location = 3 },
    new PlacementLocation { Column = 4, Row = 9, Location = 4 },
    new PlacementLocation { Column = 5, Row = 9, Location = 5 },
};

var placementLocations = new PlacementLocations(placementLocationList);

...
```

**Update:**
if you need predefined locations list you can use some sort of factory...

```
public class LocationsFactory
{
    public static PlacementLocations GetPredefinedLocations()
    {
        var placementLocationList = new List<PlacementLocation>
        {
            new PlacementLocation { Column = 1, Row = 9, Location = 1 },
            new PlacementLocation { Column = 2, Row = 9, Location = 2 },
            new PlacementLocation { Column = 3, Row = 9, Location = 3 },
            new PlacementLocation { Column = 4, Row = 9, Location = 4 },
            new PlacementLocation { Column = 5, Row = 9, Location = 5 },
        };

        return new PlacementLocations(placementLocationList);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you make `PlacementLocations` implement `IEnumerable<PlacementLocation>` and add an `Add()` method, you could even write `new PlancementLocations { new PlacementLocation { Column = 1, Row = 9, Location = 1 }, … }`, or even `new PlancementLocations { { 1, 9, 1 }, … }` if that's what you prefer.

Comment: Values ​​are fixed and can not be changed.

Comment: @Sun Rise, As you see the Placements object doesn't have external setters. Only constructor - values won't change after initialization. You can use a factory to create predefined location sets.

Comment: I changed class. Whether this way is true? what is factory ?

Comment: @Sun Rise, by factory I mean some class that will build particular 'Locations' instances for you, while the base 'Locations' class will not be tied to specific values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your class is not reusable, as it uses a specific initialization.

Write a basic 'PlacementLocations' and a specialized and separate class with your initialization. Or do the initialization in the class using your PlacementLocations.

The latter is the usual case.

I would only recommend writing an own class with the specific initialization if these values represent something special which will be used more often.